# Software That Quickly Joins Images?

Tags: image-processing

I often find that I have to join images together in a certain order, with a given number of rows and columns, so I am often finding myself using [this website](https://old.photojoiner.net/).

I was wondering if there is some software I could download to Ubuntu and/or Linux Mint, which can do the same thing?

I realise that I could just use a generic image editor like Gimp, but I'm after something that can do this quickly and easily.

Preferably I would like to:

- Join any number of images together, with any number of rows or columns in the final composite image
- Automatically shrink input images, so that the number of pixels along the common axis is the same
- Add or remove margins between images if I like

Do not care if it's GUI or CLI based, or about the image format it outputs.

Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to do something like this with [`imagemagick`](https://imagemagick.org/). You could also ask over at [SE software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: found pretty much the same question over at SE superuser. It has been answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/290656/combine-multiple-images-using-imagemagick). It even has exactly the same example picture.